# set up .htaccess for loading page from public in zend framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I want to ask you how to configure and where to save `.htaccess` for automatically displaying `index.php` page from public folder. Currently only folders of my project are showing and I must open the public folder for loading my home page.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding an htaccess in your case is not the solution for your problem. It sounds more like you should change your server public folder location.

Right now your sever is serving the root folder of your application:

```
\application_root_folder
```

But the server should serve the public folder:

```
\application_root_folder\public
```

You can do this for example in Apache config for your virtual host (if you are using Apache)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /application_root_folder/public
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: few weeks ago I solved similar problem with nette framework, i think that it is the same problem, but in nette I only create .htaccess file in root of my project with following content (index.php was located in www directory in nette):<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^$ www/ [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www/
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1
</IfModule>

Comment: Yes, but i would say it is dangerous and something is bound to go wrong. You should not expose any other folders then public.

Comment: On top of that, with your proposed rewrite rules I can still open all your project  files. I can easily expose your database config including username and password. Give me a link to the website and I will demonstrate...

Comment: i work only on localhost, or there arent any other way how to automatically redirect to public folder?

Comment: @user5503823 So why not use the `.htaccess` you wrote in the comment?